# ManagedBean processing when browser is closed

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Is there any way to capture closing of browser or being redirected to other pages at managedBean to do some processes? I know that @PreDestroy is called when the container decides to kill the managedBean. However, that is not quite what I need. I want to do an immediate processing right after the view is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript events and Ajax4JSF from Richfaces. This code calls `Bean#callBean` method if the page unloads. More information on a4j jsfunction you can find [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/jsFunction.jsf).

```
<h:body onunload="unload()">

   <a4j:jsFunction name="unload" action="#{bean.callBean}">
   </a4j:jsFunction>
</h:body>
```

Comment: is there any other methods other than using richFaces?